# JavaScript check Cookie after Write seems to need sleep

Tags: javascript, setcookie

I have a fancy Problem. Some JavaScript checks, if it's possible to write a Cookie.
This is our Code:

```
function logCookieError(){
  var noCokkieSet = false;
  createCookie('testcookie','testvalue',1);
  if(getCookie('testcookie') != 'testvalue'){
    noCokkieSet = true;
    _log.error("XMPP=NO COOKIES:");
  }else{
    eraseCookie('testcookie');
  }
  return noCokkieSet;
}
```

Unfortunately sometimes (tested with Chrome), we receive a false, though nothing has changed.
So, does writing the Cookie takes some time, and I'd need to add a sleep, or could something else influence this test?

Regards,
-Rainer

**Edit**:
I thought, createCookie and getCookie were Standard-JavaScript Methods. Here's the implementation:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days){
  if (days){
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }else{
    expires = "";
  }
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function getCookie(NameOfCookie){
  if (document.cookie.length > 0){
    begin = document.cookie.indexOf(NameOfCookie+"=");
        >-if (begin != -1){
      begin += NameOfCookie.length+1;
      end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
      if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
      return unescape(document.cookie.substring(begin, end));
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: You need to add what `createCookie`, `getCookie` and `eraseCookie` do, or add a reference to the library you are using.

Comment: Writing a cookie is a synchronous and extremely fast operation. I suspect that `getCookie`, `createCookie` and `eraseCookie` methods don't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

check your createCookie function. 
Possibly you are attempting to create a timed out cookie which is automatically terminated.
A good example resides at:
[Quirksmode org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)